# Airflow task XComArg result not found

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG which is built like this:

```
...
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
}


@dag(default_args=default_args, start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1), schedule_interval=None, tags=['mimir'])
def data_comparism_psql():
    @task(task_id="pull_release_data_from_blob")
....
@task(task_id="deviation_calculation_metrik_calls_mean_execution_time_std_dev")
    def compare_release_files(release_data_export: List[Dict], querytype: Querytype):
     ...
....
release_data_calls = get_files_from_blob(querytype=Querytype.CALLS)
report_calls = compare_release_files(release_data_calls, querytype=Querytype.CALLS)["significant_differences"]
report_calls_std_dev = compare_release_files(release_data_calls, querytype=Querytype.STD_DEV)["significant_differences"]
release_data_mean_exec_time = get_files_from_blob(querytype=Querytype.MEAN_EXEC_TIME)
report_mean_exec_time = compare_release_files(release_data_mean_exec_time, querytype=Querytype.MEAN_EXEC_TIME)["significant_differences"]
report_mean_exec_time_std_dev = compare_release_files(release_data_mean_exec_time, querytype=Querytype.STD_DEV)["significant_differences"] 
create_release_report([report_calls, report_mean_exec_time, report_calls_std_dev, report_mean_exec_time_std_dev], "Queries")


data_comparism_dag = data_comparism_psql()
```

Somehow in the `create_release_report` it fails:

```
...
 File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom_arg.py", line 342, in resolve
    raise XComNotFound(ti.dag_id, task_id, self.key)
airflow.exceptions.XComNotFound: XComArg result from deviation_calculation_metrik_calls_mean_execution_time_std_dev at data_comparism_psql with key="significant_differences" is not found!
```

If I check every step in the `Airflow UI` its green + additionally checking the XCom of the reference task, I can find `significant_differences`...

Any tip would be helpful, I tried several approaches also with task dependencies but it didn't work.

Comment: compare_release_files returns a "return_value" key unless you add multiple_outputs=True in the task decorator that create xcom key from each key in the return dictinaty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to return each key of the return value you should set the task decorator of compare_release_files with multiple_outputs=True.

otherwise the value of the xcom id "return_value" and its value its a dictionary.